# ggseasonplot in R showing error to use X=object

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, forecasting

My 1-year time series dataset is

```
water_ts<- xts(x = water[,-1], order.by = water$DATE) 

head(water_ts)
           Total_water.received.for.the.month.M3 Total_MWh
2017-01-01                               4539014      38.0
2017-01-02                               4616418      32.7
2017-01-03                               4752335      58.3
2017-01-04                               4979395      96.2
2017-01-05                               5054494      32.4
2017-01-06                               5238897      75.9

class(water_ts)
[1] "xts" "zoo"
>
```

Now I want to do seasonal plot. With the help from @Rob J Hyndman robjhyndman,
I have written following code.

>

```
 ggseasonplot(water_ts, x = Total_MWh, year.labels=TRUE, year.labels.left=TRUE) +
+   ylab("kwh") +
+   ggtitle("Seasonal plot: energy consumption kwh")
Error in ggseasonplot(water_ts, x = Total_MWh, year.labels = TRUE, year.labels.left = TRUE) : 
  object 'Total_MWh' not found.
```

Why this error is coming? I am not getting any reference.

## The reproducible data

```
dput(head(water_ts))
structure(c(4539014, 4616418, 4752335, 4979395, 5054494, 5238897, 
38, 32.7, 58.3, 96.2, 32.4, 75.9), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC", index = structure(c(1483228800, 
1483315200, 1483401600, 1483488000, 1483574400, 1483660800), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(6L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Total_water.received.for.the.month.M3", 
"Total_MWh")))
```

Comment: Can you add reproducible data? `dput(head(water_ts))` ?

Comment: @zx8754, I have edited and added the reproducible data.

Comment: Not sure if this solves it, but don't you want Total_MWh as a y input, not x? But looking at the manual pages, it looks like `ggseasonplot` wants a `ts` object, but you're giving it a `xts` object---I don't know how strict of a difference that is